# Trusting "Content-Type" on File Uploads

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, multipartform-data

If I'm supporting the upload of content (mostly images and video) by my REST API's users, is it *safe* to trust the `Content-Type` they declare in (multipart) uploads? Or should I, instead, run some kind of "media type detection" on the content (using, for example, Apache Tika) to ensure that the declared media type corresponds to the detected, actual one? Am I being over-zealous by introducing this media type detection step?

Comment: If any of he answers provided solves the problem, please accept, upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly shouldn't blindly trust the `Content-type` header, or any other header. These things should be used to inform your decisions about how to process the request. So, `Content-type: application/json` should allow you to interpret the message body as a json object - that sort of request might then be passed to a JSON deserialiser to bind it to an object.

It would be wrong to ignore the `Content-type` header just because the request body contains data which *looks* like something else. If the request is internally inconsistent then it should be rejected. It's one thing not to send a `Content-type` header but quite another for the header to be *wrong*.

So, the only situation where you might want to use some sort of automatic detection should be where you have no reasonable information about the content - either `Content-Type` is very generic (such as "*/*") or not present at all. In that situation it's worth deciding whether some kind of autodetection is possible or valuable.

Answer (score 2):

Never trust the input which you get from the user. Always run a check in your server side code be it type of file, size of file, etc. Use the REST API or Javascript to make the experience of the user smoother and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely reject all the requests that are missing `Content-Type` header (and `Content-Length` as well) or have it set incorrectly.

It's definitely not about being over-zealous, rather about securing the system. If you have suspicions about the content just check it. But remember to validate the size before checking the content. If you have a proxy server (e.g. nginx) it has appropriate modules to reject requests that are too big.