# Trusting content type from a client

Tags: file-upload, webserver, content-type, rfc2616

I have seen the answers on this SO question: [Trusting "Content-Type" on File Uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500686/trusting-content-type-on-file-uploads)

And they make sense intuitively.

However, according to RFC 2616 Sec 7.2.1,

> "If and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field,
>   the recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of
>   its content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify
>   the resource."

I would like to know the reasoning behind this part of the RFC when applied to server - why should a server trust the client's header and only fall back on content inspection if it is missing? Efficiency is one reason I can think of. Or perhaps I am misinterpreting the RFC?